# Sorting the numbers when units are added

Tags: shiny

I am trying to add the units to numbers in the dataframe. But I see after formatting, sorting is not working as expected (since the column is now characters). I need to sort as per numbers only (Millions coming at last). But this is not happening

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("tab")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  format_numbers <- function (df, column_name){
    df[[column_name]] <- ifelse(nchar(df[[column_name]]) <= 5, paste(format(round(df[[column_name]] / 1e3, 1), trim = TRUE), "K"),
                                paste(format(round(df[[column_name]] / 1e6, 1), trim = TRUE), "M"))
  }
  
  df <- data.frame(x = c(12345,35666,2646575,345))
  
  df$x <- format_numbers(df, "x")
  
  output$tab <- renderDT({
    datatable(df,escape = F)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new column and sort by the original one :

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("tab")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  format_numbers <- function (df, column_name){
    df[[column_name]] <- ifelse(nchar(df[[column_name]]) <= 5, paste(format(round(df[[column_name]] / 1e3, 1), trim = TRUE), "K"),
                                paste(format(round(df[[column_name]] / 1e6, 1), trim = TRUE), "M"))
  }
  
  df <- data.frame(x = c(12345,35666,2646575,345))
  df$NewX = format_numbers(df, "x")
  df <- df %>% arrange(x)
  
  
  output$tab <- renderDT({
    datatable((df %>% select(-x)),escape = F)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the time. But this does not work. It sorts but when we/user clicks on the sorting arrow, the sorting does not happen as expected. Please try once